# Unity3d Android vs PC rendered scene appearance

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity. I've made a scene (following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5GFoI38DOg)) and on my mac it looks ok. but on my android device it looks terrible.

how can I achieve the same look?

on my mac:

[image]

on my android:

[image]

Comment: Check shaders you use for water and ground - probably they fallback to lower shader as are not supported on android device.

Comment: It is set to standard

Comment: What Android version you use? Also what device?

Comment: Nexus 6P with Android 6.0.1. But the Minimum API Version is set to android 4.0

Comment: Btw, are you using GI? Enlightment?

Comment: in scene Precomputed Realtime GI is on (realtime resolution is set to 8) and Baked GI is off

Comment: I see. So I think the problem is not in shader but in lightning. I dont have experiance with enlighten engine, so cant really help. But try to find some options that probably sets realtime gi off for android, like quality settings. Check default quality settings for android if they include GI.